# Excel workbook creating undeletable sheeets during execution

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365

I'm getting more and more Sheets in my workbook?

[image: Illustraion of the sheets I need to remove]

Does anybody know how I delete these additional sheets?
I'm running excel 365 and the file is located on a sharepoint.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I haven't had any luck regarding this issue. However, I found others dealing with the same issue. The solution I came up with might help, and is quite simple:
Save the document as a xlsx file. This deletes the phantom sheets. Then manually transfer forms and macros and save the document as an xlsm file. Not a pretty solution. But it works.